# How to display popup window (not tool window) from Visual Studio extension?

Tags: c#, popupwindow, vs-extensibility, visual-studio-sdk

I want to unobtrusively ask users of my extension to donate after 2 weeks of usage.
A non-modal window would be better than a modal one.

Comment: [Excuse me while I pimp my template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cd71e4c8-3414-40a4-88e2-cb90e779f7ce), which makes it easy to create a DialogWindow popup.

Answer (score 1):

What stopping you using a normal WinForm Form and calling it's DoModal() method.  Try to find the top level windows of Visual Studio to pass in as the parent.

However your users make hate you, when they start up Visual Studio, and find that after the morning cut of coffee, it has blocked on your window!

Comment: ReSharper does it, so it must be okay :)